# Cannot convert type Any? To type AnyObject? When converting to swift 4 from swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook-graph-api

Trying to get my code to compile from swift 3 to swift 4.

I'm using ObjectMapper : [ObjectMapper FROM Github](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper)

And I'm getting the following 2 error messages

Cannot convert value of type '**Any?**' to type '**AnyObject?**' in coercion error
Optional chain has no effect, expression already produces '**Any?**'

```
let likesRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/likes", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, picture, user_likes", "after": after!])
let _ = likesRequest?.start() { (connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, result2 : Any?, error : Error?) -> Void in
let facebookLikes = Mapper<FacebookLikesListObject>().map(JSON: result2 as AnyObject?)
```

**FacebookLikesListObject.swift**

````
import UIKit

class FacebookLikesListObject: Mappable {
    var likes : [FacebookLikeObject]?
    var after : String?
    var before : String?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        likes <- map["data"]
        after <- map["paging.cursors.after"]
        before <- map["paging.cursors.before"]
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

`Any` is used for structs and/or classes
whereas `AnyObject` is used for classes exclusively.

You can upcast from an `AnyObject` to `Any` safely, but you cannot do the opposite.

So, you can attempt to cast to AnyObject safely

```
   if let downCastedResult2 = result2 as? AnyObject{
      let facebooklikes = Mapper.map(JSON: downcastedResult2)
   }else{
     //fallback
   }
```

OR

You can force cast

```
    let facebookLikes = Mapper<FacebookLikesListObject>().map(JSON: result2 as! AnyObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
guard let objects = result2 as? AnyObject else { return }
let facebookLikes = Mapper<FacebookLikesListObject>().map(JSON: objects)
```

Comment: This worked. Many thanks.             guard let objects = result2 as? AnyObject else { return }
            let facebookLikes = Mapper<FacebookLikesListObject>().map(JSON: objects as! [String : Any])

Comment: please accept my answer if it helps so other can get advantage if in same issue